# CakePHP set variable in view for use in layout

Tags: php, cakephp, layout, cakephp-2.1

I've got a CRUD application, and in my views there are links to actions from various controllers e.g.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Docs'), array('controller' => 'docs', 'action' => 'index')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Doc'), array('controller' => 'docs', 'action' => 'add')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Images'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Image'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add')); ?>

//etc..
```

Now, I also have a default.ctp layout with a sidebar that I'd like to dynamically populate with the action links from each view being rendered.  I know that I can move the actions from my controllers to their respective models and set variables in a beforeRender() callback within a controller, however i'd like to keep my actions within the controllers, and instead set an array within a view and pass it to the default.ctp layout.  Here's what I have so far:

**Docs/index.ctp**:

```
$links_array = array(
    'list_docs' => array('controller' => 'docs', 'action' => 'index'),
    'add_doc' => array('controller' => 'docs', 'action' => 'add'),
    'list_images' => array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index'),
    'add_image' => array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add')
    );
$this->set('links', $links_array);
```

**Layouts/default.ctp**:

```
print_r($links);
```

This returns `Notice (8): Undefined variable: links [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 93]` I'm guessing because the layout is being rendered before the view.

What's the best way to go about doing this without moving actions to their models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$links_array = array(
'list_docs' => array('controller' => 'docs', 'action' => 'index'),
'add_doc' => array('controller' => 'docs', 'action' => 'add'),
'list_images' => array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index'),
'add_image' => array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add')
);
$this->set('links', $links_array);
```

... should be in the controller.

The layout will see any variable that is available in the view. So `$links` will be visible in the layout. (and if you really have to set vars from the view instead of the controller, you don't need to use `$this->set()` in the view, just use `$links = ...`).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using View blocks? The manual even uses a sidebar as an example for it's use; [Using View Blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks)

```
// In a view file.
// Create a navbar block
$this->startIfEmpty('navbar');
echo $this->element('navbar', array('links' => $links_array));
$this->end();

// In a parent view/layout
echo $this->fetch('navbar');
```

Comment: Pretty nifty, I tend to like the idea of defining an array within a controller, keeping code separate, but I'll definitely have to remember this one.

Comment: Well, both approaches are valid ways to achieve it, that's the reason I added this answer - to show the alternatives to (future) readers

Answer (score 0):

This is even better: [using blocks for script and css files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files)

You can define a block name, like *scriptBottom*.
Append contents to it and display in the right place on your layout or another view.

```
// In your view
$this->Html->script('carousel', ['block' => 'scriptBottom']);
$this->Html->script('custom', ['block' => 'scriptBottom']);

//or
$this->startIfEmpty('scriptBottom');
$this->append('scriptBottom', $this->script('custom2'));

// In your layout or another view
<?= $this->fetch('scriptBottom') ?>
```